# Multiple forms in a single page with the help of slider

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am providing a screenshot of a Reactjs 5.0.3 page. I am trying to slide the bar of 3 forms so that if anyone clicks on the forms name (Project, Hire, General forms) user can fill the form but not redirecting to any page.

Reactjs code example which i am working on:
Single example of the Project Code I provided with you

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Styles.css'

const Forms = () => {
  return (
    <div className="webportal-content">
    <div className="container">
        <div id="firstpageid">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="#" className="leftsidelink active">Project</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="#" className="slidelink" id="showregister">Hire</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="#" className="slidelink" id="lastone">General</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div Style="display:none" id="secondpageid">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="#" className="leftsidelink" id="showlogin">Project</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="#" className="slidelink active">Hire</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="#" className="slidelink" id="thirdone">General</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div Style="display:none" id="thirdpageid">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/contact" className="leftsidelink" id="showlfirstone">Project</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/contact" className="slidelink" id="showsecondone">Hire</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/contact" className="slidelink active">General</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="wearehirings">
            <div id="page">
                <input type="hidden" value="95" id="page_id" name="page_id"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="" id="page_url" name="page_url"/>
                <div id="content-login" Style="height: 737px;">
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="webportal-section">
                            <form className="cmxform" id="fupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>First Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname" name="firstname" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname" name="lastname" required/>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" name="email" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>Phone Number</label>
                                                <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" name="phone" required onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>How you found us?</label>
                                                <input type="text" placeholder="How you found us?" id="contact_via" name="contact_via" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>Inquiry Type</label>
                                                    <select id="inquiry_type" name="inquiry_type" required>
                                                        <option value="">Select Inquiry Type</option>
                                                        <option value="Request for services">Request for services</option>
                                                        <option value="Alliance partnership">Alliance partnership</option>
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                                <label>Your Requirement</label>
                                                <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Requirement" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-12">
                                            <div className="docu-form-group form-group " id ="captcha1">
                                            <div className="g-recaptcha-contact" data-sitekey="Your Site Key" id="RecaptchaField1"></div>
                                                <input type="hidden" className="hiddenRecaptcha" name="qt_hiddenRecaptcha" id="qt_hiddenRecaptcha" required/>
                                            </div>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="submit leavemgmntsw">
                                            <button type="submit" name="submit" className="btn m-inq inq btn-hover-effect btn-hover-effect--effect-1 submitBtn" value="SUBMIT">Submit</button>
                                       </div>
                                       <div className="statusMsg" ></div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            <div id="content-register" Style="height: 830px;">
        
        <div className="content">
                <div className="webportal-section">
                    <form className="cmxform" id="fupForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                      <input type="hidden" value="95" id="contact_id2" name="contact_id2"/>
                    <div className="webportal-content">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname2" name="firstname2" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lastname2" name="lastname2" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Email Address</label>
                                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email2" name="email2" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone2" name="phone2" required onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Position applied for</label>
                                    <select id="position2" name="position2" required>
                                        <option value="">Select Position</option>
                                                                                <option value="15728">Python Developer</option>
                                                                                <option value="15722">Data Scientist</option>
                                                                                <option value="15380">Data Engineer(Exp: 2+ years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="14966">vellore-pernambut</option>
                                                                                <option value="14716">Cost Accountant (Exp: 2 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="14709">Angular Js Developer  (Exp: 1 To 2 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="14294">Content Writer(Exp: 5 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="14289">ReactNative Developer(Exp: 2 To 4 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="14283">Blockchain Developer(Exp: 2 To 5 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7154">PHP Developer (Exp: 1 To 3 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="9668">Android Developer (Exp 3 to 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="9651">Flutter Developer (Exp 3 to 5 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="9671">Dotnet Developer (Exp 2 to 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="9650">iOS Developer (Exp 3 to 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7537">Senior Fullstack Developer (Exp: 5 to 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7539">Magento Developer (Exp: 3 To 6 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7552">Mern Developer (Exp: 1 To 2 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7568">ROR Developer (Exp: 3+ Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="7570">Node JS Developer (Exp: 4 To 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="9305">Java Developer (Exp: 4 To 8 Years)</option>
                                                                                <option value="other">Other</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {/* <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group other_div" Style="display:none;">
                                    <label>List the position you are looking for</label>
                                 <input type="text" placeholder="Position" id="position_detail2" name="position_detail2" >
                                </div>
                            </div> */}
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Upload Resume</label>
                                    <input type="file" placeholder="Resume" id="file" name="file" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-12">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group ">
                                    <label>Your Message</label>
                                    <textarea id="message2" name="message2" placeholder="Message" required Style="display:block;"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-lg-12">
                                <div className="docu-form-group form-group " id ="captcha2">
                                    <div className="g-recaptcha-quote" data-sitekey="Your Site Key" id="RecaptchaField2"></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" className="hiddenRecaptcha" name="ct_hiddenRecaptcha" id="ct_hiddenRecaptcha" required/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="submit leavemgmntsw">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" className="btn m-inq inq btn-hover-effect btn-hover-effect--effect-1 submitBtn2" value="SUBMIT"/>Submit<button/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="statusMsg2" ></div>
                    </div>    
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the issue? We can't really help address any issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] of the code you are working with, and to provide more details on what you are trying to do and what any specific problems you face, including errors/stacktraces and any debugging steps, etc?

Comment: Thank you so much for solution . Now i edited the post and provided with the code and that you can tell where i am getting the issue and how to resolve them.Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add your CSS to the post? If you can, see if you can createa ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the code you are trying to use that we can inspect live.

Answer (score 0):

create component which will have all this forms.
pass the current selected prop and return the related form

example

```
const Dummyform(currentTab) => {
    switch(currentTab){

   case project:{return "project form"}

   case hire:{return "hire form"}

   case general:{return "general form"}
  }
}
```

I hope this will fix your issue